# Transmit RF signals (433Mhz) with Windows 10 IoT Core?

Tags: windows-iot

Is there a library/sample/tutorial to transmit RF signals on a rPi2 and a 433Mhz Rf Transmitter for Windows 10 IoT Core? 
Maybe a port for WiringPi? Or a NPM module (which doesn't wrap WiringPi)?

Comment: What interface does the 433 transmitter use? Serial? I2C? You can have a look at https://github.com/ms-iot/samples for all those types of interface connections.

Answer (score 3):

In case someone stumble up on here asking how to send 433Mhz signals, in my case for switching radio outlets, take a look at my **HomeAutomation** project for Windows IoT https://github.com/naice/HomeAutomation/ (it is heavily work in progress, don't blame me ;-) ) take a closer look for the **o433Mhz** project.

> It is common that the sending will not work properly if the debugger
>   is attached due to the fact that it slows down execution which will
>   affect the signal, keep that in mind.